# Examples of time complexity $O(n^k)$

Tags: time-complexity, polynomial-time

I am looking for some algorithms(examples) whose time complexity is given by $O(n^k)$. It could be any problems that you have come across. Please reply. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid this is way too broad. One natural example is to consider all subsets of size k from an n-element universe.

Answer (score 2):

**Nesting for-loops climbs the asymptotic ladder by one power per  nesting typically**
(typically only, as it depends on the body and loop-parameters).

This is a good to keep in mind when nesting loops while coding.

**Consider the algorithms $P_{k}$ which have $k$ nested for-loops. Each $P_k$ is $O(n^{k})$:**

$P_1$

```
For i = 1 to n do i := i + 1
```

$P_2$

```
For i = 1 to n do

     For j = 1 to i do j := j + 1
```

...

$P_k$

```
For i_1 = 1 to n do 

      For i_2 = 1 to i_1 do

          For i_3 = 1 to i_2 do 

            ...

              For i_k = 1 to i_{k-1} do i_k := i_k + 1
```

$P_1$ is clearly linear-time $O(n)$

$P_2$ is $O(n^2)$.

**Write out the $i$ and $j$ values for $P_2$ corresponding to the program's execution:**

**i = 1:** j = 1

**i = 2:** j = 1, j = 2

**i = 3:** j = 1, j = 2, j = 3

...

**i = n:** j = 1, j = 2, j = 3, ... , j = n

This typical triangle shape occurs for $O(n^2)$ algorithms.

Recall that $1 + ... + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, the proof of which is based on doubling the triangle, making a rectangular shape, then halving the result to get the outcome.

In general, deepening the nesting of for-loops by 1 (typically) raises the power in the asymptotic classification by 1.

**You can also simply let the variables $i_j$ run from $1$ to $n$** (rather than $i_{j-1}$). This creates a more ``artificial" example which is obviously $O(n^{k})$ for $k$ loop nestings.

The code given for $P_k$ is a little closer to practical nested for-loop cases. The example is still artificial, but it illustrates a principle behind many cases of $O(n^k)$ behaviour.

Algorithms in the literature for which the time analysis is $O(n^k)$ tend to fit the above pattern of loop-nestings tied to asymptotic behaviour. Bubble-sort is an obvious examples of $O(n^2)$ algorithms fitting this pattern. Insertion-sort also, be it that one of the loops is a while-loop rather than a for-loop. The same type of principle (typically) applies.

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad. For the purposes of this discussion, I will assume k is a constant s.t. $k\neq k(n)$. One example of an algorithm that is $O(n^k)$ would be finding the maximum value of a k-dimensional array of size $n^k$. Another would be summing the values of a k-dimensional array of size $n^k$.

Comment: $n$ represents the input size. So you cant have an array of size $n^k$. Finding the maximum value is a problem that takes $O(n)$.

Comment: @nirshahar: things are not that simple. When you consider the Gaussian algorithm for linear system resolution, the time complexity is often cited as $O(n^3)$, though the input size is $O(n^2)$, not $O(n)$.

Comment: Its up to conventions in this case. I think its a bad practice to write it as O(n^3), if the input size is O(n^2). But using some other notation, e.g $O(k^3)$, or $O(m^3)$ or even $O(N^3)$ to make sure the reader understands immediately that it does not refer to the exact input size. But once again - those are only the conventions I believe in, so as long as the reader can perfectly understand what $n$ or $k$ or whatever symbol you are using is, then do whatever you prefer.

Comment: @nirshahar: do you make a difference between $n$ and $N$ ? Notice that for matrix multiplication, if the input size is $O(n^2)$, then the time *is* $O(n^3)$ and nothing else.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on the context of usage. It doesn't *mean* anything, but rather its just a use of conventions.

Answer (score 0):

In parameterized complexity, the class XP contains all problems that can be solved in time $O(n^{f(k)})$ where $k$ is the size of the parameter, and $f$ is some computable function.

Note that ${n \choose k} = O(n^k)$, so any algorithm that tries to find a solution of size $k$ in a set of $n$ elements have a similar running time. For example brute force algorithm for many well-known NP-hard problems has such a running time where $k$ is the solution size.

Some examples are:

- Independence number, clique number, vertex cover number: Try all subsets of size $k$ and test if the chosen set is a solution.
- Hitting set: Try all subsets of size $k$ of the ground set.
- Set packing: Try all subfamilies of size $k$ of the given family of sets.

Comment: Aren't your examples $O(k n^k)$ rather than $O(n^k)$? (Unless your testing of each subset averages O(1) or so, but you're not saying that.)

Comment: Yes you’re right. I am used to ignoring the polynomial factor for hard problems (using the O-star notation). So this might not answer your question in general.